# Is it possible to use session value in guides line AmCharts?

Tags: java, php, session, amcharts

I'm using AmCharts in my program with guides line.
These guide lines i tested with some values see code below.:

```
 "guides": [{
        "value": 17.3,
        "toValue": 17.3,
        "lineColor": "#FF3C1E",
        "balloonText": "17.3",
        "fillAlpha": 1,
        "fillColor": "#FF3C1E",
        "position": "right",
        "label": "Max grens"
    }, {
        "value":  16.5,
        "toValue": 16.5,
        "lineColor": "#CCF500",
        "balloonText": "16.5",
        "fillAlpha": 1,
        "fillColor": "#CCF000",
        "position": "right",
        "label": "Target"
    }, {
        "value": 15.2,
        "toValue": 15.2,
        "lineColor": "#FF3C1E",
        "balloonText": "15.2",
        "fillAlpha": 1,
        "fillColor": "#FF3C1E",
         "position": "right",
        "label": "Min grens"
    }],
```

I tryed to pas my session value into that like this: `"value": <?php $_SESSION["RMFRtarget"]; ?>,`
But that dos'nt work.

Can anybody help me, i'm little bit stuck on it.

Comment: did you started the session on top of the file? does RMFRtarget session contain anything? is the value a float number (or maybe a string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about my comment. You just simply forgot to echo the value of your session variable:

```
"value": <?php echo $_SESSION["RMFRtarget"]; ?>
```

Comment: is it also possible to use this after the value? [code]if ($test = 1){ echo $_SESSION["RMVRMax"];} 
if ($test = 2){ echo $_SESSION["RMFRmax"];}
if ($test = 3){ echo $_SESSION["RColorLMax"];}
if ($test = 4){ echo $_SESSION["RColoraMax"];}
if ($test = 5){ echo $_SESSION["RColorbMax"];}[/code] i tryed it but dos'nt work or do i something wrong?